# Where is better to question about word segmentation and database indexing

Tags: discussion

I ask question about `word segmentation and database indexing` at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612202/look-for-a-good-solution-to-index-chinese-japanese-and-korea-word-in-database), but there seems few people paid attention to this question.
So I think if I put this question wrong place? Because it is also about indexing software, can I post it to `Superuser` or `Programmers`?

Comment: Are you actually working with `sphinx`?  If so, then adding that tag to your question might help a bit.  Right now your tags are very broad so it is unlikely you'll get many people looking at this.

Answer (score 5):

The question is not clear.

The tags you have used are also very generic - they don't tell people what technology you are using (which would make for better tags and more visibility for your question).

You have posted no code - so no one can even guess as to the language and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

I suggest reading about [writing good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - edit your question and improve it following those guidelines.

---

As for if this is suitable to Programmers or Super User - no, it isn't. Before you post on any Stack Exchange site, I suggest reading the help center pages about what is and is not on-topic on a site.

Comment: I have updated my question.Because I am asking for some solution, it is hard to add code to it.What I can do is only to say all my thought.Is my question clear now?